# Can have in my case foreign key duplicated value?

Tags: sql, mariadb

can have in this case foreign key duplicated value? Or better just have an index on column?

Here is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE customers(
id INT (10) NOT NULL,
name  VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
city  VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE orders(
cus_id INT (10) NOT NULL ,
order_date  DATETIME NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE products(
id INT (5) NOT NULL,
product_name  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
product_price INT(10) NOT NULL
);
```

But in orderitems table (Where I have stored the ordered products, the customer can have multiple products ordered so the foreign key value (cus_id) can be duplicated)

```
CREATE TABLE ordered_items(
id INT (10) NOT NULL,
cus_id INT (10) NOT NULL,
product_id  INT(5) NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE customers ADD CONSTRAINT customer_id PRIMARY KEY ( id ) ;
ALTER TABLE orders ADD CONSTRAINT customers_id_fr FOREIGN KEY ( cus_id ) REFERENCES customers ( id );
ALTER TABLE ordered_items ADD CONSTRAINT ordered_items_fr FOREIGN KEY ( cus_id ) REFERENCES customers ( id );
```

EDIT:
Sorry the ordered_items table have a unique ID column as well.

Comment: *can have in this case foreign key duplicated value? Or better just have an index on column?* could you provide more details/be more specific on the question of this post?

Comment: @lemon Thank you for your answer, yes of course. I created a working example what I mean with duplicated values in foreign key. https://sqlize.online/sql/mariadb/656608183628f76a87822383757e3900/
As you can see in this example I have duplicated value in ordered_items table on cus_id column. Is this okay? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! you can have multiple value of `cus_id` inside `ordered_items`. however, your intention is better served if you replace `cus_id` by `order_id` from `orders`, Thus your relationship would sound like,

```
    a **customer** can have multiple *orders*, 
    an **order** can have multiple *order items*,
    and an **order item** can only have single *product*
```

your sql would look like this

```
CREATE TABLE customers(
id INT (10) NOT NULL,
name  VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
city  VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE customers ADD CONSTRAINT customer_id PRIMARY KEY ( id ) ;

CREATE TABLE orders(
id INT (5) NOT NULL,
cus_id INT (10) NOT NULL ,
order_date  DATETIME NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE orders ADD CONSTRAINT order_id PRIMARY KEY ( id ) ;
ALTER TABLE orders ADD CONSTRAINT customers_id_fr FOREIGN KEY ( cus_id ) REFERENCES customers ( id );

CREATE TABLE products(
id INT (5) NOT NULL,
product_name  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
product_price DOUBLE NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE products ADD CONSTRAINT product_id PRIMARY KEY ( id ) ;

CREATE TABLE ordered_items(
id INT (10) NOT NULL,
order_id INT (10) NOT NULL,
product_id  INT(5) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE ordered_items ADD CONSTRAINT ordrItm_id PRIMARY KEY ( id ) ;
ALTER TABLE ordered_items ADD CONSTRAINT ordrItm_order_frK FOREIGN KEY ( order_id ) REFERENCES orders ( id );
ALTER TABLE ordered_items ADD CONSTRAINT ordrItm_prd_frK FOREIGN KEY ( product_id) REFERENCES products ( id );
```

Comment: Just an another question. If I have multiple records in ordered items to one customer ID "an **order** can have multiple *order items*," and I want to list out only the customer data with JOINED ordered_items table how can I do it without getting duplicated rows? 

SELECT name FROM `customers` INNER JOIN orders ON orders.cus_id = customers.id INNER JOIN ordered_items ON ordered_items.order_id = customers.id INNER JOIN products ON products.id = ordered_items.product_id

Comment: It all Depends on what you want to extract about customer, 1) If you only need list of customers which have order you need to do something like  `SELECT DISTINCT CUSTOMER ...`, 2) If you would like to parameterize your selection say for total amount/quantity ordered you need aggregation function such as `SUM(COLUMN_HERE)`. Better to specify your exact need on a new question. On more thing if you are going with the modified version of the answer you need to join `ordered_items` with `order` like `INNER JOIN ordered_items ON ordered_items.order_id = order.id`. Cheers